# bash: cannot execute binary file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to get compile some C code from within Cygwin on 64-bit Windows and call the executable using some parameters. The compilation goes through fine (the Makefile is below). But when I run the executable, I get the error `cannot execute binary file`.

A quick shows that indeed the binary is built for Linux.

> ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
>   linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
>   BuildID[sha1]=0x7d39e30cb249d2047815de23a9df33fccf91a58f, not stripped

How can I change the Makefile so that it compiles for Windows?

---

Here is the Makefile

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .u
CC= gcc

CFLAGS = -g -Wall -O3 -DHAVE_INLINE -DGSL_RANGE_CHECK_OFF
# LDFLAGS = -lm -lgsl -latlas -lgslcblas
LDFLAGS = -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
# LDFLAGS = -lm -lgsl -latlas -lcblas
LOBJECTS= a.o b.o c.o 
LSOURCE= a.c b.c c.c 

windows: $(LOBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LOBJECTS) -o stm $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cygwin is 32 bits, not 64 bits.  This is the error you get when trying to run a 64 bit program in a 32 bit environment.

edit:
Oh, and you can't compile C for Windows from inside cygwin.  There are C compilers for Windows, I know little about them.

Comment: Or the MinGW fork [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/), which also has 64bit support.